# Invalid fix up found,type 0x0001

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm32

I have these 3 .asm files and 1 c file.

Exp3_1.asm

```
NAME MAIN
.386
.MODEL FLAT, C

  printf          PROTO  :ptr sbyte, :VARARG
  scanf         PROTO  :ptr sbyte, :VARARG
 includelib  libcmt.lib
 includelib  legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
;DATA   SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
CRLF    MACRO                       ;�س�
        invoke printf, offset FMT, addr CRLFT
        ENDM
PRINT   MACRO A                     ;��ӡ����
        invoke printf, offset FMT, addr A
        ENDM
READ    MACRO A                     ;��ȡ����
        invoke scanf, offset FMT, addr A
        ENDM
SHOWVALUE MACRO A, B
        PRINT A
        MOV AX, B[EBX]
        LEA ESI, VALUE
        CALL F2TO10
        MOV BYTE PTR [ESI], 0DH
        MOV BYTE PTR [ESI+1], 0AH
        MOV BYTE PTR [ESI+2], 0
        PRINT VALUE
        ENDM
CHANGEVALUE MACRO A, B
        LOCAL LL
LL:     PRINT A
        MOV AX, B[EBX]
        LEA ESI, VALUE
        CALL F2TO10
        MOV BYTE PTR [ESI], 0
        PRINT VALUE
        PRINT SEPARATOR
        CALL GETVALUE
        CMP DI, 1
        JE LL
        MOV B[EBX], DX
        ENDM

.DATA
MENUT   DB 'Please Enter a Number(1~9):', 0

INNAMET DB 'User Name:', 0
WRONGNAMET DB 'Invalid User Name', 0
INNAME  DB 10 DUP(0)
INPWDT  DB 'Password:', 0
WRONGPWDT DB 'Invalid Password', 0
INPWD   DB 10 DUP(0)
LOGINST DB 'Login in', 0
INGOODT DB 'Good Name:', 0
WRONGGOODT DB 'Invalid Good Name', 0
INGOOD  DB 10 DUP(0)
CHANGEGOODT DB 'Good Selected', 0
NOGOODT DB 'No Goods', 0
SELLGOODT DB 'Good Sold', 0
NOTSELECTEDT DB 'No Goods Selected', 0
UPDATEPRIOT DB 'Priority Updated', 0
NOTBOSST DB 'Authrity Denied', 0
BPRICET DB 'Buying Price:', 0
SPRICET DB 'Selling Price:', 0
BAMOUNTT DB 'Buying Amount:', 0
SAMOUNTT DB 'Selling Amount:', 0
VALUE   DB 8 DUP(0)
SEPARATOR DB '->',0
BNAME   DB 'GUSHIYU', 0         ;�ϰ�����
BPASS   DB '153426', 0              ;����
AUTH    DB 0                        ;��ǰ��¼״̬��0��ʾ�˿�״̬
GOOD    DD 0                        ;��ǰ�����Ʒ��ַ
N       EQU 30
SNAME   DB 'SHOP', 0                ;�������ƣ���0����
GA1     DB 'PEN', 7 DUP(0), 10      ;��Ʒ���Ƽ��ۿ�
        DW 35, 56, 70, 25, ?        ;�����ۣ����ۼۣ����������������������Ƽ���
GA2     DB 'BOOK', 6 DUP(0), 9      ;��Ʒ���Ƽ��ۿ�
        DW  12, 30, 25, 5, ?        ;�Ƽ��Ȼ�δ����
GAN     DB N-2 DUP( 'TempValue' , 0, 8, 15, 0, 20, 0, 30, 0, 2, 0, ?, ?)
                                    ;������ƷĬ��ֵ
CRLFT   DB 0DH, 0AH, 0
A       DB 'A', 0                       ;������
B       DB 'B', 0
FMT     DB '%s', 0
FMTC    DB '%c', 0
CHAR    DB 0

.CODE
;START: MOV AX, DATA                ;����ʼ
        ;MOV DS, AX

;MENU:  PRINT MENUT             ;���˵�
        ;MOV AH, 01H
        ;INT 21H
        ;CRLF
        ;CMP AL, '1'
        ;JE CF1
        ;CMP AL, '2'
        ;JE CF2
        ;CMP AL, '3'
        ;JE CF3
        ;CMP AL, '4'
        ;JE CF4
        ;CMP AL, '6'
        ;JE CF6
        ;CMP AL, '8'
        ;JE CF8
        ;CMP AL, '9'
        ;JE OVER
        ;JMP MENU
;CF1:   CALL FUNC1
        ;JMP MENU
;CF2:   CALL FUNC2
        ;JMP MENU
;CF3:   CALL FUNC3
        ;JMP MENU
;CF4:   CALL FUNC4
        ;JMP MENU
;CF6:   CALL FUNC6
        ;JMP MENU
;CF8:   CALL FUNC8
        ;JMP MENU

FUNC1   PROC                        ;����1
        ;LOCAL CHECK_USER, CHECK_PWD, WRONG_NAME, WRONG_PWD, LOGIN_S
        PRINT INNAMET               
        READ INNAME
        CRLF
        LEA EDI, INNAME
        LEA ESI, BNAME
CHECK_USER:                         ;���ֽڱȽ��û���
        MOV AL, [EDI]
        CMP AL, [ESI]
        JNE WRONG_NAME
        INC EDI
        INC ESI
        CMP AL, 0
        JNZ CHECK_USER
        PRINT INPWDT
        READ INPWD
        CRLF
        LEA EDI, INPWD
        LEA ESI, BPASS
CHECK_PWD:                          ;���ֽڱȽ�����
        MOV AL, [EDI]
        CMP AL, [ESI]
        JNE WRONG_PWD
        INC EDI
        INC ESI
        CMP AL, 0
        JNZ CHECK_PWD
        JMP LOGIN_S
WRONG_NAME:
        PRINT WRONGNAMET
        CRLF
        RET
WRONG_PWD:
        PRINT WRONGPWDT
        CRLF
        RET
LOGIN_S:                            ;��½�ɹ�
        MOV AUTH, 1
        PRINT LOGINST
        CRLF
        RET
FUNC1   ENDP

FUNC2   PROC                        ;����2
        ;LOCAL CHECK_GOOD, CHECK_NAME, WRONG_GOOD, CHANGE_GOOD
        PRINT INGOODT               
        READ INGOOD
        CRLF
        MOV EAX, -1
CHECK_GOOD:                         ;ѡ����һ���Ƚ���Ʒ
        INC EAX
        CMP EAX, 30
        JE WRONG_GOOD
        MOV ECX, EAX
        IMUL ECX, 21
        ADD ECX, OFFSET GA1
        MOV ESI, ECX
        LEA EDI, INGOOD
CHECK_NAME:                         ;�Ƚ���Ʒ��
        MOV BL, [EDI]
        CMP BL, [ESI]
        JNE CHECK_GOOD
        INC EDI
        INC ESI
        CMP BL, 0
        JNZ CHECK_NAME
        JMP CHANGE_GOOD
WRONG_GOOD:
        PRINT WRONGGOODT
        CRLF
        RET
CHANGE_GOOD:                        ;����ѡ����Ʒ
        MOV EBX, EAX
        IMUL EBX, 21
        ADD EBX, OFFSET GA1
        MOV GOOD, EBX
        PRINT CHANGEGOODT
        CRLF
        SHOWVALUE BPRICET, 11
        SHOWVALUE SPRICET, 13
        SHOWVALUE BAMOUNTT, 15
        SHOWVALUE SAMOUNTT, 17
        RET
FUNC2   ENDP

FUNC3   PROC                        ;����3
        MOV EBX, GOOD               
        CMP EBX, 0
        JE NO_SELECTED
        MOV AX, 15[EBX]
        MOV DX, 17[EBX]
        CMP AX, DX
        JNE SELL_GOOD
        PRINT NOGOODT
        CRLF
        RET
SELL_GOOD:
        INC DX
        MOV 17[EBX], DX
        PRINT SELLGOODT
        CRLF
        CALL FUNC4
        RET
NO_SELECTED:
        PRINT NOTSELECTEDT
        CRLF
        RET
FUNC3   ENDP


FUNC4   PROC                        ;����4
        ;LOCAL COMPUTE_PRIO, COMPUTE_OVER
        PUSH EBP
        MOV EBP, -1                 
        PRINT UPDATEPRIOT
        CRLF
COMPUTE_PRIO:
        INC EBP
        CMP EBP, 30
        JE COMPUTE_OVER
        LEA ESI, GA1
        MOV ECX, EBP
        IMUL ECX, 21
        ADD ESI, ECX
        MOV EBX, ESI
        ADD EBX, 13
        MOV AX, [EBX-2]
        MOV BX, [EBX]
        MOVSX EAX, AX
        MOVSX EBX, BX
        MOV EDI, 128
        IMUL EDI
        IDIV EBX
        MOV ECX, EAX
        MOV EBX, ESI
        ADD EBX, 15
        MOV AX, [EBX+2]
        MOV BX, [EBX]
        MOVSX EAX, AX
        MOVSX EBX, BX
        IMUL EDI
        MOV EDI, 2
        IDIV EDI
        MOV EDX, 0
        IDIV EBX
        ADD EAX, ECX
        MOV EBX, ESI
        ADD EBX, 19
        MOV [EBX], AX
        JMP COMPUTE_PRIO
COMPUTE_OVER:
        POP EBP
        RET
FUNC4   ENDP



FUNC8   PROC                        ;����8
        ;LOCAL GET_LETTER, IS_NUM, SHOW_OVER
        PUSH BP
        MOV BP, 4                   
        MOV BX, CS
GET_LETTER:
        MOV CL, 4;
        ROL BX, CL
        MOV DL, BL
        AND DL, 0FH
        CMP DL, 0AH
        JB IS_NUM
        ADD DL, 07H
IS_NUM: ADD DL, 30H
        invoke printf, offset FMTC, DL
        DEC BP
        JZ SHOW_OVER
        JMP GET_LETTER
SHOW_OVER:
        CRLF
        POP BP
        RET
FUNC8   ENDP

F2TO10  PROC
        PUSH BX
        PUSH CX
        PUSH DX
        MOV BX, 10
        XOR CX, CX
LOP1:   XOR DX, DX
        DIV BX
        PUSH DX
        INC CX
        OR EAX, EAX
        JNZ LOP1
LOP2:   POP AX
        CMP AL, 10
        JB L1
        ADD AL, 7
L1:     ADD AL, 30H
        MOV [ESI], AL
        INC ESI
        DEC CX
        JNZ LOP2
        POP DX
        POP CX
        POP BX
        RET
F2TO10  ENDP

FUNC6   PROC
        CMP AUTH, 0
        JE NOT_BOSS
        CMP GOOD, 0
        JE  NOT_SELECTED
        MOV EBX, GOOD
        CHANGEVALUE BPRICET, 11
        CHANGEVALUE SPRICET, 13
        CHANGEVALUE BAMOUNTT, 15
        CHANGEVALUE SAMOUNTT, 17
        RET
NOT_SELECTED:
        PRINT NOTSELECTEDT
        CRLF
        RET
NOT_BOSS:
        PRINT NOTBOSST
        CRLF
        RET
FUNC6   ENDP

GETVALUE PROC
        PUSH AX
        PUSH CX
        XOR DI, DI
        XOR CX, CX
        XOR DL, DL
        PUSH DX
LOOP1:  invoke scanf, offset FMTC, ADDR CHAR
        POP DX
        MOV AL, CHAR
        CMP AL, 0DH
        JE RETURN
        CMP AL, 0AH
        JE RETURN
        CMP AL, '0'
        JB ERR
        CMP AL, '9'
        JA ERR
        SUB AL, '0'
        MOV CL, AL
        MOV AX, DX
        MOV DX, 10
        MUL DX
        ADD AX, CX
        MOV AH, 0
        MOV DX, AX
        PUSH DX
        JMP LOOP1
ERR:    CRLF
        MOV DI, 1
        POP CX
        POP AX
        RET
RETURN: POP CX
        POP AX
        RET
GETVALUE ENDP
        END
        ;END START
```

func6.asm

```
NAME FUNC6
        PUBLIC FUNC6
        EXTERN F2TO10:NEAR, NOTSELECTEDT:BYTE, NOTBOSST:BYTE, BPRICET:BYTE, SPRICET:BYTE, BAMOUNTT:BYTE, SAMOUNTT:BYTE, VALUE:BYTE, SEPARATOR:BYTE, AUTH:BYTE, GOOD:WORD, CRLFT:BYTE
PRINT   MACRO A                     
        LEA DX, A
        MOV AH, 09H
        INT 21H
        ENDM
CRLF    MACRO                       
        LEA DX, CRLFT
        MOV AH, 09H
        INT 21H
        ENDM
CHANGEVALUE MACRO A, B
        LOCAL C
C:      PRINT A
        MOV AX, B[BX]
        LEA SI, VALUE
        CALL F2TO10
        MOV BYTE PTR [SI], '$'
        PRINT VALUE
        PRINT SEPARATOR
        CALL GETVALUE
        CMP DI, 1
        JE C
        MOV B[BX], DX
        ENDM
CODE    SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
        ASSUME CS:CODE
FUNC6   PROC
        CMP AUTH, 0
        JE NOT_BOSS
        CMP GOOD, 0
        JE  NOT_SELECTED
        MOV BX, GOOD
        CHANGEVALUE BPRICET, 11
        CHANGEVALUE SPRICET, 13
        CHANGEVALUE BAMOUNTT, 15
        CHANGEVALUE SAMOUNTT, 17
        RET
NOT_SELECTED:
        PRINT NOTSELECTEDT
        CRLF
        RET
NOT_BOSS:
        PRINT NOTBOSST
        CRLF
        RET
FUNC6   ENDP

GETVALUE PROC
        PUSH AX
        PUSH CX
        XOR DI, DI
        XOR CX, CX
        XOR DX, DX
LOOP1:  MOV AH, 01H
        INT 21H
        CMP AL, 0DH
        JE RETURN
        CMP AL, 0AH
        JE RETURN
        CMP AL, '0'
        JB ERR
        CMP AL, '9'
        JA ERR
        SUB AL, '0'
        MOV CL, AL
        MOV AX, DX
        MOV DX, 10
        MUL DX
        ADD AX, CX
        MOV DX, AX
        JMP LOOP1
ERR:    CRLF
        MOV DI, 1
        POP CX
        POP AX
        RET
RETURN: POP CX
        POP AX
        RET
GETVALUE ENDP
CODE    ENDS
        END
```

F2TO10.asm

```
NAME F2TO10
        PUBLIC F2TO10
.386
CODE    SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
        ASSUME CS:CODE
F2TO10  PROC
        PUSH BX
        PUSH CX
        PUSH DX
        MOV BX, 10
        XOR CX, CX
LOP1:   XOR DX, DX
        DIV BX
        PUSH DX
        INC CX
        OR EAX, EAX
        JNZ LOP1
LOP2:   POP AX
        CMP AL, 10
        JB L1
        ADD AL, 7
L1:     ADD AL, 30H
        MOV [SI], AL
        INC SI
        LOOP LOP2
        POP DX
        POP CX
        POP BX
        RET
F2TO10  ENDP
CODE    ENDS
        END
```

main.c

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern void FUNC1();
extern void FUNC2();
extern void FUNC3();
extern void FUNC4();
extern void FUNC6();
extern void FUNC8();

int main()
{
    int op = 0;
    while (op != 9)
    {
        printf("SHOP:MY SHOP\n");
        printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("1.Login in\n2.Select good\n3.Buy good\n4.Update recommendation\n6.Update good\n8.Show CS\n9.Exit\n");
        printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Please Enter a Number:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        printf("*********************************************\n");
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:

            FUNC1();
            break;
        case 2:
            FUNC2();
            break;
        case 3:
            FUNC3();
            break;
        case 4:
            FUNC4();
            break;
        case 6:
            getchar();
            FUNC6();
            break;
        case 8:
            FUNC8();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        printf("*********************************************\n");
        system("pause");
        system(("cls"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am creating the project using visual studio 2019 and masm32 as include path. When trying to compile and create object files, there are no errors, but when it is a time to link all .obj files, i get this error:

Error   LNK1190 invalid fixup found, type 0x0001    Lab3    C:\Users\Blaise\source\repos\Lab3\FUNC6.obj

How can i solve this problem? is it because of older link.exe file? i am using link.exe version 5.12

Comment: `USE16` - you can't link 16-bit code with 32 or 64-bit C compiler output.  What kind of executable are you trying to make?

Comment: i am trying to have .exe file so that i use debug in visual studio. How can i use 16 bit compiler in visual studio?

Comment: You can't, AFAIK.

Comment: is there another solution?

Comment: Sure, write 32 or 64-bit code that can be part of a native Windows executable.